# How are we sure that the measured proton spin puzzle will be also observed similarly in the neutron thus a neutron spin puzzle?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, neutrons

The EMC experiment in 1988 using muons' deep inelastic scattering, has reported that the [contribution](https://physicsworld.com/a/the-spin-of-a-proton/) of the valence quarks triplet (i.e. up-up-down) in the proton was measured to contribute as little as 4% to 24% (i.e. $0.02\hbar$ to $0.12\hbar$) of the total spin of the proton $0.5\hbar$ contrary to the theoretical predictions. This is actually an almost null result which shocked the science community and has lead to the [Proton Spin Crisis](https://physicsworld.com/a/the-spin-of-a-proton/). After more than 30years this is still regarded as an [unsolved problem in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics).

**However, I'm fascinated why as far as I know, this was never verified by experiment also to be true for the quarks triplet contribution (down-down-up) to the $0.5\hbar$ spin of a neutron?** It is my understanding and correct me if I'm wrong, that it is only assumed that the same discrepancy will also hold for the case of the neutron.

Nevertheless, you can never be sure unless you do the actual experiment. Why they haven't tested yet this assumption today for the neutron?

As far as I know testing this might be quite a challenge since the neutron has no charge and will not respond to deep inelastic scattering technique when inside the nucleus. Also, I'm not sure if deep inelastic scattering can be applied in a free neutrons experiment and also because their short life time.

Are there any other reasons why we cannot test by experiment the quarks contribution to the spin of a neutron? Imagine how surprising it would be if the contribution of the valance quarks triplet in the neutron spin is different than that of the proton and possible much closer to theoretical predicted?

[image: neutron]

Comment: [Lots](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.022002) of experiments. The "crisis"-"puzzle", "paradox", etc, self-serving blather reflects irresponsible science reporting stunts (the link you provide is one of the major offenders: I should know, having been my division's representative in it!). The ["spin crisis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_spin_crisis) is definitely ***not*** a burning problem in physics, and buying its existence itself  relies on unwarranted hyper-confidence on poor ***models***. Ab initio lattice QCD calculations  do not disagree with experiment on this.

Comment: So there was actually a measurement of the neutron valance quarks contribution that is significantly closer to the predicted value for the nucleus (i.e. proton or neutron) by a SLAC experiment after the EMC proton 1988 reported almost null result (4%-24%). Namely a staggering 60% contribution of the valance quarks to the spin of the neutron with similar collision energies with EMC. However here in this SLAC experiment there were electrons used and not muons we had in the EMC experiment he difference of the two measurements for proton and neutron spin valance quarks contribution is about 2σ.

Comment: here is the link:  https://inspirehep.net/files/e9ce4a03e531451e76314f12d808a3b2 (see Abstract of linked thesis)
So I guess I was right about my intuition that the two different nucleons may differ in the valance quarks spin contribution. However, this is not widely known.

Comment: Here is the above mentioned E 142 SLAC experiment of 1992 with the analysis of the data finished at 1996 were also the paper was published in PRW: https://tinyurl.com/5n7u6yp7